# How to specify wildcard filenames for .Zip type files in Python Variables

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

My requirement is

I'm calling a function to extract files/folders from a .Zip file

```
files_extract_with_structure(file_source, file_dest)
```

`file_source` and `file_dest` are the variables I'm passing to the above function and the value of the `file_source` variable is defined as below.

```
file_source = "/dbfs/mnt/devadls/pre/Source_Files/2022-10/767676.XXX.XXX.XXXX.20221010090858.txt.zip"
```

where `767676.XXX.XXX.XXXX.20221010090858.txt.zip` is the zip file name

The above function works fine if I pass the `file_source` variable value as above (hardcoded the zip file name)

My requirement is instead of hard coding the zip file name, Can we specify the wild card file names as below?

```
file_source = "/dbfs/mnt/devadls/pre/Source_Files/2022-10/767676.XXX.XXX.XXXX.*.txt.zip"
```

because I will receive the same file with a different date in the next month and so on...

But when I specify the wildcard names as `"767676.XXX.XXX.XXXX.*.txt.zip"`, it is throwing a `No such file or directory error.

Kindly help to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module from the standard library, it will let you filter and match filename based on unix-like rules.

With your example, something like this should work:

```py
from fnmatch import fnmatch

file_source = "/dbfs/mnt/devadls/pre/Source_Files/2022-10/767676.XXX.XXX.XXXX.20221010090858.txt.zip"
pattern = "/dbfs/mnt/devadls/pre/Source_Files/2022-10/767676.XXX.XXX.XXXX.*.txt.zip"


if fnmatch(file_source, pattern):
    files_extract_with_structure(file_source, file_dest)
else:
    print("No file found")
```

The next step might be to list the files in the source directory, and for each to test against the pattern.

Hope this will help!